# Issue unexporting remote object in Java

Tags: java, rmi

I'm building a simple program for an assignment, which consists of:

- A .jar file that launches a registry and a database service.
- Another .jar file that connects to the registry and launches another two services (auth and management), both connecting via registry to the database service.
- A third .jar file that can be executed several times, each launching a separate user client that connects to both auth and management services, and also launches its callback.

The services and callback inherit from UnicastRemoteObject so I don't needd to export them when initializing everything. Everything works flawlessly until the time comes to shut everything down. For reference, this is the code for launching, getting and stopping the services. It's the same for all three, since the URL are defined when the registry is created. The closeCallback method receives its own URL, that's all.

```
public String launchDataServ(ServicioDatosInterface dataServ) throws RegException {
    try {
        this.reg.bind(this.dataServURL, dataServ);
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        throw new RegException("error message 1");
    } catch (AlreadyBoundException e) {
        throw new RegException("error message 2");
    }
    
    return this.dataServURL;
}


public ServicioDatosInterface getDataServ() throws RegException {
    try {
        return (ServicioDatosInterface) this.reg.lookup(this.dataServURL);
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        throw new RegException("error message 1");
    } catch (NotBoundException e) {
        throw new RegException("error message 2");
    }
}


public void closeDataServ() throws RegException {
    try {
        UnicastRemoteObject.unexportObject(this.getDataServ(), true);
         this.reg.unbind(this.dataServURL);
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        throw new RegException("error message 1");
    } catch (NotBoundException e) {
        throw new RegException("error message 2");
    }
}
```

When I exit the user clients, they throw a NoSuchObjectException when invoking unexportObject() on their callbacks. When I exit the "server", it throws a NoSuchObjectException when invoking unexportObject() on either the auth or the management service. But when I exit the database, it doesn't throw any exception.

Needless to say, I don't call the close() methods anywhere in the code except for the final part, when the program ends, and everything works perfectly up until that point.

Commenting unexportObject() makes the program hang up instead of making a clean exit because I haven't unexported the services, so apparently they are exported just until the moment I need to unexport them. Also, I don't understand why this issue doesn't happen with the database service.

Comment: Are you trying to unexport stubs? Unexporting the result of a lookup looks very like that. You can't unexport a stub, only the actual remote object, which you don't normally get from a `Registry` lookup.

Comment: So I can't get the remote object via lookup and have to supply it via argument? No problem doing that, but, again: that exact process works for the database service, no issues at all. What's making me crazy is *why* does it work on one service but not the others.

Comment: Jesus Christ it worked. This is black magic and I absolutely HATE that it works without knowing why. A million thanks, but could you please elaborate a little on the reason this works inconsistently and why am I able to unexport the database stub?

Comment: The reason is that you didn't get a remote object from the Regsitry,  as I said. You get the stub, and you can't unexport that. If however you created the Registry yourself with `createRegistry()` *and* you use the result of that method to call `bind()`, instead of using `getRegistry()` or `Naming`, you aren't doing RMI to the registry, you are doing local method invocation: so the RMI stub substitution doesn't occur.